# Extended vs Basic Use Case

Tags: uml, use-case

In my module/subsystem, trimmed down version of core data processing of the parent system will be used ONLY so which one (option 1/2/3) is correct?

[The Core Data Processing is the real and complete business case but the subsystem, to which this diagram belongs, will not use this complete scenario but just some parts of it]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 and 3 are both correct. I haven't seen option 1 before.

If you only use Core Data Processing in one place, I wouldn't bother extending it. That is, use option 3 if you don't reuse Core Data Processing in more than one place, otherwise use option 2.

Usually you want your use case diagrams to be as simple as possible, so avoid specifying too much. Do you really need to specify Core Data Processing in this use case? If you think it's important at this level, then include it. Otherwise, just stick with the simplest diagram that gets the message across.

Comment: option 1 is shown in all extend examples but they expect that both use cases are part of the system, which is not the case here, so i think option 3 would be the best. I am waiting for more answers :)

Answer (score 2):

option 1 means that Trimmed Data Processing (TDP) is never triggered directly by the actor but executed when a condition X (the one you could specify in an extension point) becomes true. 
So it is a flow path that NOT in all the execution of Core Data Processing (CDP) happens. User executes CDP and sometimes CDP give the flow control to TDP. In this case TDP is NOT required to be a complete use case (see after).

option 2 means option 1, if you add an association btw the actor and CDP, plus the fact that the user can trigger TDP directly. Options 2 makes not so much sense to me as is ( but I haven't understood very well the semantic of yours use cases).

option 3 means that TDP is an autonomous flow triggered directly by the user and, as a complete use case: it brings value to the value-chain and leave the system in a consistent state.

Option 1 and option 3 can be both correct but at different level (1 @ business level and 3 @ system level). Clearly in this interpretation the actor of option 1 is different from the actor of option 3, and more specifically, the actor of option 3 is CDP (which in fact "invokes" TDP in option 1).

About option 1 and 2 I agree with Oleksi do not show extended use cases if they are not reused among different others use cases.

Comment: hmm, since there is no way to accept multiple answers and Oleksi answered first and i am agree with him (you looks too) so i am accepting his answer

Comment: @bjan, it's fine and I agree. But I think that you could mark my answer as useful (if you find it really so :) ).